# when does select for update in gorm release the lock?

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

halo i use postgresql as my rdbms and this is the first time i use gorm as my orm. so i have i flow to update data with `select for update` in my code i put it in function like this:

```
// func getUser
var user model.User
repo.db.WithContext(ctx).Clauses(clause.Locking{Strength: "UPDATE"}).
        Preload("User").Where(&criteria).First(&user)
```

and then i have update query like this:

```
// func updateUser
result := repo.db.WithContext(ctx).
        Session(&gorm.Session{FullSaveAssociations: true}).Updates(&user)
```

so the usecase would be like this:

```
user := getUser()
err:= updateUser(user)
```

my question is, will `updateUser` release the lock or i need to call transaction explicitly like `tx.Begin()` and `tx.Commit()` to release the lock?